# Socket Blocked when Reading Huge Content Length in Python URLLIB2

Tags: python, urllib2, python-sockets

I'm using Python to consume a web service that returns a *JSON* response. When the content length of the response is not that big, everything goes perfectly. It appears that the issue comes in front when the content length of the response is extremely huge.

This is a snippet of my code, pretty simple:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = response.read()
response.close()
```

Where **request** is a correctly formed **urllib2.Request**.

If I print **response.info()** it gives me:

```
Content-Type: application/json 
Content-Length: 3244749 
Connection: close Date: Thu, 05 Jun 2014 20:24:23 
GMT Server: EESBServer
```

My script stucks forever in the **response.read()**, as if the socket were blocked.

I've been looking for a solution, have not found one yet.

I would really really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. It was just a parameter of the server that I wasn't awared of. The mentioned parameter was limiting the amount of data that could be read through connection.

Answer (score 1):

consume the response in chunks, for example:

```
response.read(1024)
```